# Add a custom taxonomy to Wordpress post loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm building a page where i want to display posts from the category, 'Recycled Aggregates' in a Bootsrap Accordion. I've managed to display each post in a new Panel which is great but now i need to display a custom taxonomy on each of these which is called 'Stock levels'.

What i've got so far... (which doesn't output the value)

Can anyone shed any light to why this isn't working?

Kind Regards,

Shaun

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<?php foreach(get_the_terms($wp_query->post->ID, ‘stock-levels’) as $term);?>
  <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=10&posts_per_page=10' ); while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <div class="container">
    <a data-toggle="collapse"  class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title"> 
        <?php the_title(); ?><div class="stock-level"><?php echo $term;?></div>
        </h4></a> 
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 recycled-image">
        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
       <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
      </div>

      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     </div>
    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the right way of doing it, but for a quick fix just add the parameters below to the wp_query, replace TAXONOMY_NAME By the name of the taxonomy and TAXONOMY_TERM by the term within that taxonomy

```
new WP_Query( 'cat=10&posts_per_page=10&TAXONOMY_NAME=TAXONOMY_TERM' )
```

EDIT:
Well then add $args array before the query and replace wp_query with the one below.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'TAXONOMY_NAME',
        ),
    ),
);
$catquery = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer! The problem is with what you suggested is each post will have the same term?

Comment: Or you can even use your query like this 
new WP_Query('cat=10&posts_per_page=10&taxonomy="TAXONOMY_NAME")

Comment: Hi i still can't get this to work even when using your answer :/ 

My aim is to set a custom taxonomy to each post under the category 10 and then in my page template display these posts and their taxonomy value? 

I've used in the past this: (which worked on a page template not a post loop)
<?php foreach(get_the_terms($wp_query->post->ID, ‘stock-levels’) as $term);?>

<?php echo $term;?>

Comment: I dont know about your scenario, you might have already considered it. but what i think you are talking about the term of the category. So if 'Movies' is the taxonomy and 'action_movies' is the term, when someone goes into 'action_movies' you want to show all posts in action_movies. If this is the case then you should create a new file in your theme and name it taxonomy-movies.php. and in this file you should be able to get the current term of the taxonomy by $tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); $tax->slug;

Comment: Hey Omer, 

This is the scenario:

Comment: Hi Omer, 

Sorry for not finishing the last comment. 

Basically this page, http://www.budgetskiphirewastemanagementandrecycling.co.uk/?page_id=271 is built by posts from a category and on each of these posts is set a taxonomy which i want to display on the post on the page.